# How to remove comments from posts

Tags: support

I am trying to review posts on the site, but my settings seem to have got stuck with showing a narrative on the function buttons (see Figure screenshot below).  I have restarted my browser, the machine and searched for a relevant setting all to no avail.  Any thoughts as to how I remove this?

[image]

Comment: You need to supply details: which browser, in particular?

Comment: I'm using Safari - the latest version, although the problem was already there in the previous version. It doesn't;t happen in Chrome

Comment: Clean the cache of the browser for start.

Comment: @Tim, thanks.  Already done that - its still there....